# Ускорить процес обработки данных

Tags: python, pandas, оптимизация, dataframe

подскажите как можно ускорить процесс обработки данных.
Есть 2 столбца, если значение 2 столбца совпадает с нужным мне названием, я вытаскиваю значение из первого столбца этой же строки + проверка на одинаковые значение.
Когда в базе около 2000 строк, работает достаточно быстро, но когда их около 100 000, обработка занимает около 10сек. Есть какой-то способ уменьшить время обработки?

```
for index,row in mdlReg.iterrows():
        if row['Zonetype'] == 'Aisle':          
            a = row['zonename'] 
            if a not in self.sektor:
                self.sektor.append(a)
        if row['Zonetype'] == 'Floornum':
            a = str(row['zonename'])
            if a not in self.floor:
                self.floor.append(a)
        if row["Zonetype"] == "Sector":
            a = str(row['zonename'])            
            if a not in self.spanN:
                self.spanN.append(a)    
        if row["Zonetype"] == "Zonename":
            a = str(row["zonename"])
            if a not in self.placevalue:
                self.placevalue.append(a)
```

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе.

Comment: К сожалению воспроизводимый не могу, я подключаюсь к SQL Server, от туда вытаскиваю данные,        WRH = '*'
  QRY = f"EXEC [dbo].[IT_GetUniqueZonesTypes] @WRH = '{WRH}'"
  mdlReg = pandas.read_sql(QRY,DestDB)

Comment: воспроизводимый пример - не значит, показать реальные и тем более все данные! Приведите пример входных данных (5-10 строк) и пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе, чтобы было понятно как именно вы хотите обработать данные. PS все это описано в ссылке которую я оставил в комментарии...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вот как в ваш итератор строки попали?

Если `база` это БД - то сделайте просто свой `extract` запросами, по условиям в нём - ну дёрните 4 раза ничего страшного, но получите сразу, что хотели.

Если не БД (о извращения) - можно поменять код, внести следующие правки: 1) добавим ветвление с `elif` `else`; 2) перейте от списков к сетам (утратится порядок добавления правда, но вы не писали, что он нужен); 3) слить условия проверки типа и вхождения в конечный список 4) замутить функцию 5) замутить `map` - ну по идее хватит в рамках одного кейса.

```
from itertools import starmap

def my_check(x, y):
    if y['Zonetype'] == 'Aisle':
        self.sector_set.add(y['zonename'])
    elif y['Zonetype'] == 'Floornum':
        self.floor_set.add(y['zonename'])
    elif y["Zonetype"] == "Sector":
        self.spanN_set.add(y['zonename'])
    elif y["Zonetype"] == "Zonename":
        self.placevalue_set.add(y['zonename'])
    else:
        pass

starmap(my_check, mdlReg.iterrows())
```

Answer (score 1):

Отфильтровать по логической маске и взять уникальные значения?

```
self.sektor = mdlReg[mdlReg['Zonetype'] == 'Aisle']['zonename'].unique().tolist()
self.floor  = mdlReg[mdlReg['Zonetype'] == 'Floornum']['zonename'].unique().tolist()
self.spanN  = mdlReg[mdlReg['Zonetype'] == 'Sector']['zonename'].unique().tolist()
self.placevalue = mdlReg[mdlReg['Zonetype'] == 'Zonename']['zonename'].unique().tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаем воспроизводимый пример данных:

```
In [149]: np.random.seed(42)
     ...:
     ...: zone_types = ["Aisle", "Floornum", "Sector", "Zonename"]
     ...:
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:     "Zonetype":np.random.choice(zone_types + ["Junk"], size=100),
     ...:     "zonename":np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ"), size=100)
     ...: })
```

Исходный DF:

```
In [150]: df
Out[150]:
    Zonetype zonename
0   Zonename        G
1       Junk        I
2     Sector        H
3       Junk        L
4       Junk        B
..       ...      ...
95    Sector        D
96      Junk        C
97  Floornum        G
98  Floornum        I
99     Aisle        A

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Векторизированное решение:

```
In [152]: res = (df
     ...:        .query("Zonetype in @zone_types")
     ...:        .groupby("Zonetype")
     ...:        ["zonename"]
     ...:        .apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
     ...:        .to_dict())
     ...:
```

Результат:

```
In [153]: res
Out[153]:
{'Aisle': ['A', 'O', 'B', 'F', 'G', 'E', 'Q', 'K', 'I', 'C'],
 'Floornum': ['A', 'C', 'O', 'N', 'G', 'J', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'I', 'Q', 'B'],
 'Sector': ['H', 'P', 'E', 'C', 'J', 'M', 'K', 'I', 'A', 'F', 'D'],
 'Zonename': ['G',
  'H',
  'E',
  'N',
  'I',
  'Q',
  'D',
  'M',
  'L',
  'C',
  'F',
  'A',
  'B',
  'P']}
```

PS я думаю разложить компоненты словаря `res` по переменным труда не составит...

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, за помощь. Я переделал запрос в SQL, забрал данные, перевел в tolist() и всё стало работать в разы быстее из 10сек превратилось в 0.2сек